# Performance benchmarking nifi template flow

Tags: apache-nifi

I have developed a NiFi template, which would be run out of several client environments. I would like to know what are my options with respect to performance benchmarking the template flow against a pre-defined hardware configuration?

Answer (score 0):

This question is too broad to answer in detail, but the basic steps:
1. Set up a representative environment (with a good amount of data flowing in/out) 
2. Configure the system properly

The second step is more art than science, but the answer to this HCC question lists is a nice set of things to consider: https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/82485/nifi-sizing-benchmark-conditions-and-number-of-sou.html

It covers IO, CPU, RAM